# Passing arguments to script, getting: "Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0]"

Tags: perl, argv

**Problem:** Windows XP is not passing command line arguments to perl scripts.

**Symptom:** a simple command like:

```
say "Argument 1 (\$ARGV[0]) is: $ARGV[0], argument 2 (\$ARGV[1]) is: $ARGV[1].";
```

Resulted in:

```
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in concatenation (.) or string at...
```

**Solution:**

The root problem is in Windows XP.  The default method for starting perl passes only the first variable, which is the script name.  Result is that $ARGV[0] is uninitialized.

The fix is to edit the Windows registry at:

```
\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Perl\shell\Open\command
```

And make the entry:

```
"C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe"  %*
```

Result is:

```
C:\whatever>perl argtest.pl 1 2
Argument 1 ($ARGV[0]) is: 1, argument 2 ($ARGV[1]) is: 2.
```

Thanks especially to David W who pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: The tutorial you linked is not very high quality. It doesn't even have `use strict`.

Comment: Humour me: try `argtest 1 2 3` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried your code (Perl 5.16.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5; pretty far removed from your platform), and with `x.pl 1 2`, I got `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at x.pl line 5.` and the output
`Argument 0: 1, argument 1: 2, argument 2: .`  I'm wondering if your Perl is misleading you (though your output is consistent with `$ARGV[0]` being uninitialized).  Remember, `$0` contains the name of the script; `$ARGV[0]` contains the name of the first argument to the script.

Comment: I used $ARGV[0-2] just to cover all bases.  Nothing is being passed.

Comment: I tried argtest 1 2 3 and got the same results, the printed results are empty for all strings in the array.

Comment: what would `say "[$_]" for map $_//"!undef!", @ARGV` output? And what is `say 0 + @ARGV`? (Ooh, XP, haven't seen that one in a while)

Comment: How is `argtest` starting a Perl script on Windows? Don't you either need to include an extension (`.pl`, e.g.) that has a file association with Perl, or include the `perl` executable on the command line (e.g., `perl argtest`)? Or is it really running an `argtest.bat` script which then runs your Perl file? I suspect that the batch file is not written correctly to pass its command line arguments on to Perl.

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using?  Is an upgrade a possibility?  It looks to me like erroneous behaviour on the part of the Perl you are using, though I find it quite hard to believe.

Comment: What happens with `perl argtest.pl 1 2 3`?  This is a follow-up to @mob's suggestion...or an alternative way of diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The user is using DWIM Perl in windows (i've never used it). I tried the script with ActiveState Perl in windows without an issue (if I pass 3 arguments.

Comment: @imran: Ah; I didn't recognize DWIM Perl as a sub-species of Perl. Thanks.

Comment: C:>perl argtest.pl HELP!
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[1] in concatenation (.) or string at argtest.pl line 5.
Argument 0: .

Comment: By adding .pl as a registered extension and adding perl as the program, Windows accepts it and will execute perl automatically.  But it doesn't matter, because I can do "perl argtest HELP!" and get the same result.

Comment: Just tried with DWIM perl (5.14.2) on Win7. argtest.pl 1 2 3 (.pl is associated to perl) printing "Uninitialized value ARGV[0], but `perl argtest.pl 1 2 3` prints correct value `1`.

Comment: It looks like you got a different result. The warning message when you ran `C:> perl argtest.pl HELP` was about `$ARGV[1]`, not `$ARGV[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `@ARGV` in Perl is not quite like `argv` in C.

```
                              C          Perl

Name of the program        argv[0]        $0
1st argument               argv[1]      $ARGV[0]
2nd argument               argv[2]      $ARGV[1]
n-th argument              argv[n]      $ARGV[n-1]
```

So if you provide one command line arguments to a Perl script, it will be found in `$ARGV[0]`. `$ARGV[1]` will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that Windows knows it is supposed to use Perl to execute a program.

1. The command line begins with the perl executable and the name of the script to be run is provided as a command line argument. This is how it works on Unix and other environments, too.
2. Your system associates one or more extensions, such as `.pl`, `.pm`, and/or `.cgi` with the Perl application, and Windows will launch Perl when you type a filename with one of those extensions or click on a file with one of those extensions in the Windows explorer.

You have invoked your script simply as

```
argtest 1 2
```

and not one of

```
perl argtest 1 2
argtest.pl 1 2
```

That makes me think that Perl is not the first application that gets to look at the file referred to by `argtest`. Perhaps there is a file called `argtest.bat` or `argtest.exe` which has the task of getting Perl to run your Perl code. For some reason this intermediate program is not passing the command line arguments that you provide on to the Perl application.

Provide the code for this intermediate file and we can help some more.

---

**UPDATE:** David W proposes a 3rd way -- setting the `PATHEXT` environment variable to inclue `.pl` files and invoking `argtest` from the command-line -- see his answer.
Then if Window's file association with the `.pl` extension was messed up, say, set as just `C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl`" and not "`C:\Dwimperl\perl\binperl %*`" then the OP would get the behavior that he describes.

Comment: user did say in one of the comments that he did try `perl argtest.pl HELP!` and got the same result

Comment: Yes, I DID run it from "perl argtest.pl HELP!" and got the same results.

Comment: Actually, you said the result of running `perl argtest.pl HELP!` was that `$ARGV[1]` was uninitialized, not `$ARGV[0]`. That actually sounds like it is working the way it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and test your code in the Cygwin environment. I bet this is a Windows issue. (If you're a Unix head, you'll like Cygwin because it gives you the Unix/Linux like environment on your Windows machine. I don't use Windows without it.)

Windows uses suffixes to determine what program opens what files. Is your Perl script called `argtest`, `argtest.bat` or `argtest.pl`?

On Windows, make sure all of your Perl scripts use the `*.pl` suffix, so Windows will use whatever Perl parameter to execute them. Windows doesn't use the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Another possible issue: On Windows XP, I had a problem with Perl scripts with parameters because Windows had this as an execution string:

```
 perl %1
```

which would execute the Perl program with my script, but ignore the parameters. I had to change this to:

```
 perl %*
```

Unfortunately, Windows Vista through Windows 8 changed the way this is set. However, I have Windows 7 and don't have this issue. I did make sure to install Perl under `C:\Perl` and not `C:\Program Files\Perl` because of the space in the directory name. I also have Strawberry Perl installed.

There is a special Windows environment variable called `PATHEXT`. This allows you to type in `foo` instead of `foo.pl`. If Windows can't see how to execute your file, Windows goes through `%PATHEXT` and tries appending various suffixes until it finds one that works. You might want to append `.PL` to that environment variable, so you can type in `foo` instead of `foo.pl` all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `%PATHEXT%`. If OP's `PATHEXT` is set, and if his association for `.pl` files is just `perl` and not `perl %1` or `perl %*`, that could explain his problems.

Answer (score 0):

In `perl` file name is not part of the array of arguments. At least in the test I did you must remove `ARGV[2]` or pass three arguments, like `argtest 1 2 3`

Comment: Results of argtest 1 2 3: Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in concatenation (.) or string at C: etc.  No change.

Comment: DWIM is based on Strawberry perl, if that adds anything.  This is so basic I don't see how it can be related to DWIM.  I don't really care what perl I use, but I will be really pissed if I change to ActiveState and it's no different.